# how to design a data structure that getMedian and insert in O(1)?

Tags: data-structures, median

I thought about doing this in sort array and save the index of the median and its takes O(1). but I couldn't think about any way to do the insert in O(1) and keep the array sorted.
I really appreciate it if someone can help me with this problem

Comment: if you know something about the data being stored, like A-Z characters, then I think you can solve it, since you can still keep the data structure "sorted" when both inserting and removing items, in O(1) of time. The tradeoff is additional O(n) memory.

Comment: the problem is that i don't know the range of the numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible, because it would allow comparison-based sorting in O(n) time:

- Suppose you have an unsorted array of length n.
- Find the minimum element and maximum element in O(n) time.
- Insert all n elements into the data structure, each insertion takes O(1) time so this takes O(n) time.
- Insert n-1 extra copies of the minimum element. This also takes O(n) time.
- Initialise an output array of length n.
- Do this n times:

  - Read off the median of the elements currently in the data structure, and write it at the next position into the output array. This takes O(1) time.
  - Insert two copies of the maximum element into the data structure. This takes O(1) time.

The above algorithm supposedly runs in O(n) time, and the result is a sorted array of the elements from the input array. But this is impossible, because comparison-sorting takes Ω(n log n) time. Therefore, the supposed data structure cannot exist.